# Issues parsing JSON in Java for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json

I am learning basic Java app creation and think I'm doing ok so far, however I have fallen in regards to parsing a JSON response from a server.

I'm not even sure my response is built correctly.

Response form server:

```
[{"Q_Number":"1","Question":"This is Q1"},{"Q_Number":"2","Question":"This is Q2"},{"Q_Number":"3","Question":"This is Q3"}]
```

As you can see I get three questions given by the server, labeled 1 - 3. 
ideally what I'd like is the JSON to be parsed into string labeled: `q1String q2String q3String`.

I have tried a variety of parsing code form here and tried to make it work for me. Here is my current messy code:

```
String jsonString = a.toString();
    try {
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONObject jsonOb = json.getJSONObject("1");

        String str_value=jsonOb.getString("Question");

        Log.i("JSON",str_value);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
        // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
    }
```

This is the last error I got:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Q_Number":"1","Question":"This is Q1"},{"Q_Number":"2","Question":"This is Q2"},{"Q_Number":"3","Question":"This is Q3"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Which part of the error is confusing you? The data is a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`, so use the `JSONArray` class, not the `JSONObject` class, in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the source string to `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`
Please try this

```
    String jsonString = a.toString();
    try
    {
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for(int index = 0; index < json.length(); ++index)
        {
            JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(index);
            String str_value = obj.getString("Question");
            Log.i("JSON", str_value);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your json is an Array [], not an Object {}

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to take the JSON response as an ArrayList because it starts with Array i.e [] not an Object (curly braces) {}